# Setting up Eclipse Indigo for spring with maven

Tags: spring

I'm trying to use spring with maven in Eclipse(Indigo). please help me how to configure all these things together. 
1 It ll be helpful if given instruction on project file structure(in general). 
2 Do i still nee+ to add spring jars in my project if i have p o m . x m l ???
3 Also where to put this file in my project. Any help ll be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Tool Suite instead of bare Eclipse. See here: http://spring.io/tools
It integrates with maven too.
They also have an article on integrating with maven: http://spring.io/blog/2011/01/17/green-beans-getting-started-with-maven-and-spring/
Looks like that covers all your questions.
In short:

1. If you use maven it pretty much defines your files structure
2. you state all jars (including spring) in pom file
3. see maven tutorial above

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me. I hv one more question-- is STS better than eclipse for using spring ????

Comment: STS is based on Eclipse, so it's Eclipse with some additions for working with Spring.

Comment: @prabhatkumar Actually you can install it in your Indigo, here is the link and the list of features: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tool-suite-sts-eclipse-indigo-37#.UsvC0Phn5HY